# Do interfaces derive from System.Object? C# spec says yes, Eric says no, reality says no

Tags: c#, .net

Question is simple and asked in the title.

C# 4.0 Specification says: (§4.2.2)

> The object class type is the ultimate
>   base class of all other types. Every
>   type in C# directly or indirectly
>   derives from the object class type.

[Eric Lippert says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/not-everything-derives-from-object):

> Interface types, not being classes,
>   are not derived from object.

Reality says:

```
Type t = typeof(ICloneable).BaseType;
Console.WriteLine(t == null);
```

> True

So is spec wrong or what? Whom to believe?

Comment: "Every type in C#...", well, I know pointers don't derive directly from System.Object; so is this an example of the "indirectly derives" case, or are pointers not a type?

Comment: @codekaizen Pointers are standalone topic. They are aliens to .net world, so they don't fit into main OO concepts.

Comment: @codekaizen from Eric "Unsafe pointer types are explicitly outside of the normal type rules for the language."

Comment: Well, then... `(§4.2.2) ... Every normal type in C# directly or indirectly derives from or is convertable to the object class type.` There, I fixed it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's not quite as simple a question as you might think :)

Interfaces don't *derive* from `object` but you can call the members of `object` on them. So you can call `ToString()` on an expression which has a compile-time type of `IDisposable`, for example.

Coincidentally, I overhead a conversation between Neal Gafter and Eric at NDC discussing exactly this point...

I believe section 4.2.2 of the spec is over simplified, unfortunately. Hopefully Mads and Eric will fix it up for a future release - I'll mail them to make sure they see this question.

I'm also struggling to find anything in the spec to back up the rest of this answer. Section 3.4.5 of the C# 4 spec comes as close as I can find:

> The members of an interface are the members declared in the interface and in all base interfaces of the interface. The members in class `object` are not, strictly speaking, members of any interface (13.2). However, the members in class `object` are available via member lookup in any interface type (7.4).

The conversion from an interface type to `object` is covered by section 6.1.6:

> The implicit reference conversions are:
>
> - From any *reference-type* to `object` and `dynamic`.

Comment: Anything that implements an interface (classes or structs) is going to derive from `object`. I'm not aware of the other non-object types (e.g. pointers) being able to implement interfaces.

Comment: Would you say the spec is correct in that an interface *indirectly* inherits?  Well, it doesn't inherit in the technical sense, but the end result appears to behave as such.

Comment: I can't catch difference between *derive* and *have an effective base type*. Even if declaration of class and interface looks very similar they are essentially different, interface is just a contract. So since in .net no class can derive from something different than Object every interface reference can be cast to object. but this doesn't mean for me that they actually derive from object.

Comment: @Andrey: Effective base classes come into play in type inference and various things. However, I'm not sure that I was right about that section. Editing...

Comment: But this: "However, the members in class object are available via member lookup in any interface type (7.4)." is conclusion from fact that there is single root in hierarchy in .net. If we had "System.Object" and "System.AnotherObject" which was not descendant of Object this will not work.

Comment: @Andrey: Yes, C# assumes a single root object type.

Comment: @KingCronus: I guess it's more coincidence than irony - edited accordingly.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry to be picky...that one really gets me though! Cheers :-)

Comment: I wonder why IntelliSense suggests me to use one of `System.Object` methods even if it looks like that: `ICloneable i; i.(list of methods here)`. Maybe it knows that anything that can be `i` must derive from `System.Object` and it has to have all of its virtual methods or new methods named the same, so that's why it suggests to use one of them even if interface doesn't derive from `System.Object` class. Is that correct?

Comment: @BlackCamel: Sort of. As Andrey's own comment a bit earlier says, the spec defines that all the members of `System.Object` are always available via member lookup.

Comment: Note that C# also allows you to call **`static`** methods from `object` through an interface identifier. So not only is `IDisposable instance = ...; instance.ToString()` allowed, like you mention. Also **`IDisposable.ReferenceEquals(new object(), new object())`** is legal. It calls the `static` member of `object`. Of course an interface cannot declare its own `static` members. Addition: For type parameters, C# does not allow calls to `static` members through the type parameter name, so e.g. `T.ReferenceEquals(...)` will not compile if `T` is a type parameter. Constraining `T` does not help.

Answer (score 36):

Jon is (as usual) spot on. It is not as easy as you think!

The spec is vague and slightly contradictory. In this particular case it is probably best to squint a little bit and get the gist of what the spec *means to convey* rather than narrowly parsing it for precise definitions.

The simple fact of the matter is that "inheritance" is a very overused term in object-oriented programming. (I seem to recall that C++ has six different kinds of inheritance, though I'd be hard pressed to name them all on short notice.)

If I had my druthers then the C# specification would clearly call out a difference between *inheritance* and *interface implementation*. Inheritance is *a code-sharing technique for class (and delegate) and struct (and enum) types"; its mechanism is that *all heritable members of a base type become members of a derived type*. That is in contrast with *interface implementation* which is *a requirement that an implementing type have a certain set of public members*. Those two things seem conceptually very different to me; one is about *sharing existing members* and the other is about *requiring certain members*.

However, the spec does not do so; it conflates the two under the rubric of inheritance. Given that these two somewhat different things have the same name in the spec, it is hard to reason clearly and precisely about the differences between them.

I personally prefer to think that object is *not* the "base type" of any interface, and that the members of object are *not* inherited by the interface. That you can call them on an instance of an interface is more like a courtesy extended to you by the compiler so that you do not have to insert a cast to object in there.

---

UPDATE: I note for new readers that this answer was written ten years before default interface implementations were added to C#. This new feature does not bear directly upon the question that was asked here. However, it does muddy the waters even more!

Now we *are* in a situation where implementing classes may "inherit" not just the *requirement* to provide an implementation of an interface member, but also an *implementation* of that member. This feels much more like what we would traditionally think of as "inheritance".

Even in this new and slightly more confusing situation, I recommend that we continue to use jargon carefully:

- Inheritance continues to be the property that *members of one type are also members of another type*.
- It is still the case that any expression of any interface type is *convertible* to a reference to `object`, which may be `null`.
- It is still the case that the compiler will allow you to call members of `object` when the receiver is an expression of any interface type.

Comment: C++ has the same number of kinds of inheritance as C#- two.

Comment: @DeadMG: C++ has public, private and protected inheritance, which C# does not -- C# has only public inheritance on classes. C++ has "virtual inheritance", which C# does not. C++ has multiple inheritance, which C# does not.

Answer (score 3):

Interface types do not inherit from `Object`, but storage locations of interface types hold references to class-type objects which (if non-null) are guaranteed to inherit from `System.Object`.

I think understanding what's going on will be easiest if one starts by examining the difference between value types and class types.  Suppose I have a structure:

```
public struct SimplePoint {public int x,y;}
```

and I have two methods

```
public doSomethingWithPoint(SimplePoint pt) ...
public doSomethingWithObject(Object it) ...
```

and cal each method:

```
SimplePoint myPoint = ...;
doSomethingWithPoint(myPoint);
dosomethingWithObject(myPoint);
```

The first call does not pass a thing that derives from `Object`.  It instead passes the contents of all of `SimplePoint`'s public and private fields.  The second call needs a thing which derives from `Object`, so it generates a new heap object instance of type `SimplePoint` which contains all the public and private fields of the value-type `SimplePoint`, and loads all those fields with the corresponding values from `myPoint`, and passes a reference to that object.

Note that the type `SimplePoint` actually describes two different kinds of things: a collection of fields (i.e. the value type) and a heap-object type.  Which meaning is applicable depends upon the context where the type is used.

Interface types have a similar wrinkle: when used as storage-location types, they specify that the storage location will hold an object reference.  When used as a generic constraint, they say nothing about how the type will be stored.  Thus, a storage location of an interface type will hold a reference to a heap object that genuinely does inherit from `System.Object`, but a variable of a type constrained to an interface might hold either a reference or a bunch of fields.

Comment: The first call *does* pass a thing that derives from `object`: for example, you can call `ToString()` on it.

Comment: @svick: It is only possible to call `ToString` directly on value types which define their own implementation of that method; if one writes `3.ToString();`, it won't be performed as a virtual call to `Object.ToString(),` but will simply be performed as a direct call to the `ToString()` method which is defined for `Int32`; such a call is allowed not because `Int32` derives from `Object`, but because `Int32` defines its own `ToString()` method.  Invoking `ToString` on a value type which does not define its own version will cause the system to create a new heap object instance which...

Comment: ...holds data copied from the value type (and which does derive from `Object`), and will then call `ToString` on that.  It does that because the unboxed value type is convertible to object.  Some people try to pretend that boxed and unboxed structures are the same type.  It is true that they are described by the same `Type` instance, but given their different behavior, I think it's more helpful to regard them as being different types.

Comment: "such a call is allowed not because Int32 derives from Object, but because Int32 defines its own ToString() method." - Can you clarify this? Both the System.ValueType and Int32 override ToString() method. They do not use 'new' to hide the method, if that's what you mean by "int32 defines its own ToString()".

Comment: @thewpfguy: An instance method on a class `T` behaves as though there's a hidden parameter of type `T`.  So `Object.ToString()` has a "hidden" parameter of type `Object`, `StringBuilder.ToString()` has a hidden parameter of type `StringBuilder`, etc.  An instance member on a value types `S` will have a hidden parameter of type `ref S`, so `Int32.ToString()` has a parameter of type `ref Int32`.  Note that unlike the other parameters in a virtual function, the hidden parameter's type is different in every override.

Comment: If one defines a class `Fnord` which does not override `ToString`, then `var f=new Fnord(); f.ToString();` will attempt to pass `f` to the inherited `ToString()` function which expects an `Object`.  Such a call may be made directly.  If one tries `var int i=5; i.ToString()`, the `i` gets passed by `ref` to a method which expects a `ref int`; again, the call can be made directly.

Comment: In the case where one has a structure `Woozle` which does not override `ToString()`, a direct call would try to pass a `ref Woozle` to a method which expects a reference to a heap object derived from `ValueType`.  Since a `ref Woozle` is not a reference to any sort of heap object, a heap object must be created so `ToString` can be given a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the definition of "derives". Surprisingly, the C# specification does not have a single canonical definition for this term. Fortunately the actual behavior of code is still specified unambiguously. But it does mean some questions are hard to answer without going into hair-splitting!

- Are interfaces a **subtype** of `System.Object`? Yes.
- Does interfaces **inherit** from `System.Object`? No.

The common definition of [subtype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) is that if type A is a subtype of type B, then a value of type A can be used anywhere a value of type B is expected. A fullfills the contract of B.

By this definition, all interfaces in C# are subtypes `System.Object` since an interface instance is also an instance of `System.Object`.

For example you can do this:

```
 IComparable x = new String();
 Console.Write(x is Object); // writes "true"
```

and this:

```
IComparable x = new String();
object y = x; // implicit cast from interface to System.Object
```

and:

```
IComparable x = new String();
var y = x.ToString(); // method inherited from System.Object
```

So it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck!

**But Eric Lippert says...**

In the quote Lippert is using "derived" to refer to inheritance. All class types inherit (directly or indirectly) members from `System.Object` - but interfaces does not. Interfaces only inherit from other interfaces. So by this definition, interfaces clearly does *not* derive from `System.Object`.

But note that this is *not* a disagreement about how the language actually works, it is purely a difference in the terminology used to describe it.

The two definitions are usually equivalent in C#, but your question is one of the edge cases where it makes a difference.

**But reality says...**

Reflection is a language-independent .net API which uses the CLI terminology. This cannot be transferred directly to C# since C# is not formally depending on the CLI. (For example in CLR value types are considered different types than boxed value types, and only boxed value types are considered objects. This is not a distinction C# makes.)

But anyway, the `BaseType` property is specified like this:

> The Type from which the current Type directly inherits, or null if the
> current Type represents the Object class or an interface.

Note that this completely sidesteps the issue! It doesn't state whether interfaces *can* have a base type or not, just that it will always return null regardless. So it doesn't really answer the question.

**Bottom line**

In the end, what matters is the observable behavior of the language. The intention of the language designers is clear from a larger quote:

> C#’s type system is unified such that a value of any type can be
> treated as an object. Every type in C# directly or indirectly derives
> from the object class type, and `object` is the ultimate base class of
> all types. Values of reference types are treated as objects simply by
> viewing the values as type `object`. Values of value types are treated
> as objects by performing boxing and unboxing operations (§9.3.12).

The important point is that interfaces can always be treated as objects. Whether they "actually" derive from object is purely a philosophical discussion then.