# Why RhinoMocks obligates redefining ToString() explicitly in order to be able setting expectations on it?

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to mock `ToString()` call on my custom object. I've created a mock for the interface and setting expectation on `ToString()` call

```
interface ICustomObject
{
}

var customObjectMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICustomObject>();
var fakeDump = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
customObjectMock.Expect(c => c.ToString()).Return(fakeDump).Repeat.Any();
```

Whilst test run I got run time exception saying:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Invalid call, the last call has
>   been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a
>   virtual (C#).

Well-known error, but why I got it considering that `ToString()` is virtual?

And more interesting - I've worked it around simply by defining `ToString()` explicitly in the interface:

```
interface ICustomObject
{
  // Weird! I believe such method definition in interface would be confusing
  // without a special remark comment saying that this method is redefined 
  // to satisfy RhinoMocks (perhaps Reflection?)
  string ToString();
}
```

After this RM allows setting expectations on `ToString()`.

Just wondering why RinoMocks obligates me redefine standard virtual `Object.ToString()`? Perhaps RM does not consider such standard methods which available for each Framework's object and obligates redefining all methods/properties expl;icitly in order to be able setting expectations?

Comment: Is the `ToString()` method in your custom object really virtual, or did you override `ToString()` with your own, *non-virtual* declaration?

Comment: I just using my interface to create a mock and set expectations so not using any custom object. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) - `public virtual string ToString()`

Comment: Does RhinoMocks require you to set such expectations for other methods besides `ToString()`? Without a custom object, and in the absence of method declarations in your interface, I'm not sure how RhinoMocks would even be aware of your methods, including `ToString()`.

Comment: I expected that RM pick up `Object` methods since everything inherited from the `Object` class and would has Object's methods

Comment: Interfaces [are not objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236305/do-interfaces-derive-from-system-object-c-sharp-spec-says-yes-eric-says-no-re). Although you can call `ToString()` on an interface implicitly, the assumption is that there exists some `object` that implements your interface, and therefore provides an implementation of `ToString()` implicitly. I don't think it's as simple as you believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interfaces [are not objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236305/do-interfaces-derive-from-system-object-c-sharp-spec-says-yes-eric-says-no-re).

Although you can call `ToString()` on an interface implicitly, the assumption is that there exists some `object` that implements your interface, and therefore provides an implementation of `ToString()` implicitly.

Since you don't provide an implementation of your interface, there is nothing to "hook" the `ToString()` method, and apparently RhinoMocks figures it doesn't make much sense to test a method that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: It makes sense for me thanks again! BTW, just wondering whether it woudl be right if RhinoMocks allows setting expectations on such base Object methods, otherwise I've to redefine such methods just to satisfy RhinoMocks/(Reflection?) in interface which looks weird without special remark comment

Comment: The purpose of `ToString()` is to provide a human-readable representation of an object.  Why would you need to unit test that, other than to prove it's actually returning something?

Comment: Having complex hierarchy of the obejcts I would like to ensure that top-parent dump all childs details in ToString(). Both child/parent overrides `ToString()`. So I mocking childs, passing in the parent (root) and then calling `root.ToString()`, to provide wel--mocked childs I have to mock `ToString()` call for childs. And I'm logging this `ToString()` so thsi is pretty important point - ensure that correct info was dumped. I can provide own `public string DumpDetails()` but decided to use `ToString()`, what you think?

Comment: But if you change even one character in the implementation of any `ToString()` in the hierarchy, it breaks all of your unit tests.  Is the implementation of `ToString()` critical to your application's operation?  It shouldn't be.

Comment: I want to be sure that `root.ToString()` dumps all hierarchy details, and I'm using only one real object in test - root, all childs are mocked.

Comment: So... Ya gotta include `ToString()` in your interface. :) The declaration of `ToString()` in your interface indicates to others reading your code that `ToString()` has *special importance.*