# In C#，interface Type didn't inherit from System.Object?

Tags: c#, .net, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do interfaces derive from System.Object? C# spec says yes, Eric says no, reality says no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236305/do-interfaces-derive-from-system-object-c-sharp-spec-says-yes-eric-says-no-re)

It is said all objects in .net inherit from System.Object.
Is that true?

I try to find what object the Ilist interface inherited from on the MSDN, but there's no mention about its inheritance.

Can anyone tell me something?

Comment: Its the same question as :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236305/do-interfaces-derive-from-system-object-c-sharp-spec-says-yes-eric-says-no-re

Comment: All objects inherit from `object`. Interfaces are not objects. They are interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces themselves aren't objects in a class hierarchy.  They are "types" in the sense that they represent an object.  But they aren't concrete classes in and of themselves.

For example, you can't instantiate an `IList<int>`.  This wouldn't compile:

```
var list = new IList<int>();
```

However, you can create a `List<int>`, which does inherit from `System.Object`:

```
var list = new List<int>();
```

This instance of `list` can be viewed as lots of different interfaces.  For example:

```
var listVariantA = list as IList<int>();
var listVariantB = list as IEnumerable<int>();
```

And so on.  This is because its concrete type, `List<int>`, implements multiple interfaces.  It doesn't *inherit* from them, as they themselves are not concrete types.

It seems like where you're getting lost is in the different between inheritance and interfaces.  Some might say that interfaces are ".NET's answer to multiple inheritance" which can be a fair statement.  But there's a fundamental difference between the two concepts.  Think of inheritance as a hierarchy of what an object *is*:

```
Vehicle
  Car
    Honda Accord
    Toyota Camry
  Truck
    Ford F150
```

And so on.  Interfaces don't fit into this hierarchy.  Think of an interface, instead, as a *contract* which an object meets.  For example, all `Vehicle` object might implement the `IDrivable` interface.  Some of them might implement the `IFlyable` interface.  Some still might implement both (flying cars).