# How come an interface instance has GetType, GetHashCode, Equals and ToString methods?

Tags: c#, object, interface

Consider the following example.

```
public interface IAnimal
{
   void MakeSound();
}
public class Dog: IAnimal
{
   public void MakeSound() { Console.WriteLine("Bow-Bow-Bow"); } 
   public static void Main()
   {
      IAnimal a = new Dog();
      Console.WriteLine(a.MakeSound());
      Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
   }
}
```

How come the interface instance can access ToString method that was from System.Object? My understanding is, with interface, one can access only the methods the interface holds.

Comment: I think you are mixing a concept with language features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class implicitly derived from `System.Object` :

> Languages typically do not require a class to declare inheritance from Object because the inheritance is implicit. [[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)]

**UPDATE :**

Just found this, possible duplicate? :

[Do interfaces derive from System.Object? C# spec says yes, Eric says no, reality says no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236305/do-interfaces-derive-from-system-object-c-sharp-spec-says-yes-eric-says-no-re)

Comment: Even though your class inherits off object, I would think your interface would only know about the members of it's contract?

Comment: @Michael you're right, interface doesn't inherits object. Methods from Object class available via *member lookup*. check link above.

Comment: @har07 Yes, the answer from Eric is good in that question. But, I would like to know what happens in the compilation process to plug the interface instance to have additional methods. Even we will not be seeing those when opening the interface in ILDASM. I will look for the member lookup :)

Comment: @Prasanna That was my point too.  The compiler doesn't even tell you the direct inheritance never mind a indirect.  However the compiler and intelligence are able to.

Comment: @Michael You both mentioned JIT compiler? Coz, I don't see any change while seeing the interface in the dis-assembler. The weird thing is, I saw the following: 
.class interface public abstract auto ansi Arithmetic.IAnimal
{
} // end of class Arithmetic.IAnimal
??

Answer (score 2):

Because ***everything*** is an object.  It's a cheeseball answer, but that's how .NET works. :)

Comment: [Not](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx) everything is derived from object.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is, with interface, one can access only the methods
> the interface holds.

Actually, with an interface you can access the methods the interface holds *and* all members of `System.Object` (as you have discovered). This doesn't mean that interfaces themselves derives from `System.Object`, it just means that the compiler has a "special case" when checking for members on variables declared as interfaces.

The compiler can do this because interfaces are implemented by objects and all objects derive from `System.Object`.

So when `a` is declared as `IAnimal` it really means that the variable `a` contains an object which implement the interface `IAnimal`. This object is guaranteed to support all members in `IAnimal` *and* all members `System.Object`.