# What happens when you concat a string with an IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I trust the compiler when refactoring, but stumbled upon something bizarre.

```
public static void Main()
{       
    Console.WriteLine(List() + "wtf"); // no compilation error
}

public static IEnumerable<string> List() {
    yield return "abc";
    yield return "xyz";
}
```

Can anyone explain what the reason would be for the compiler to accept this?

PS: now that you know it does not throw an exception, guess what the console will write as output. The answer here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9nz8Bl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to guess...

When you do `someValueOrObject + string`, and *someValueOrObject* is not implicitly convertible to a string, then the *ToString()* method will be called on *someValueOrObject* to get its string representation (equivalent to `someValueOrObject.ToString() + string`).

[`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Object_ToString) is a virtual method implemented by the `System.Object` class (from which any other type in .NET derives, [exceptions notwithstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236305/do-interfaces-derive-from-system-object-c-sharp-spec-says-yes-eric-says-no-re)). Unless overridden, its default behavior is to return the (fully qualified) type name of the instance on which it is being called.

To better understand this, you might want to run this example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var l = List();
        Console.WriteLine("Type of enumerable returned by List(): " + l.GetType().FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(l + "wtf"); 
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> List() {
        yield return "abc";
        yield return "xyz";
    }
}
```

(https://dotnetfiddle.net/H0hl4O)

Assuming the type name of the compiler-generated enumerable object returned by the iterator method *List()* is "*Program+<List>d__0*", this example would produce the following output:

> Type of enumerable returned by List(): Program+<List>d__0
>   Program+<List>d__0wtf