# Is overriding object.Equals on an Interface default implementation possible?

Tags: c#

In order to reuse same code only once, and exploring interface default implementation feature, I wonder if something like this is possible :

```
public interface ITest : IEquatable<ITest>
{
    public Guid Id {get;}

    internal bool IsEqual(ITLSC? other);

    bool IEquatable<ITLSC>.Equals(ITLSC? other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        if (GetType() != other.GetType()) return false;

        return IsEqual(other);
    }

    //ERROR : override is not valid for this element
    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return ((IEquatable<ITLSC>)this).Equals(obj as ITLSC);            
    }    
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    bool ITest.IsEqual(ITest? other)
    {
        //whatever how we choose to check equality ...
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ITest> testers = new List<ITest>();
        //... Somehow populate testers list ...

        object standardTest = new Test(...);

        bool res = true;
        foreach(ITest test in testers)
        {
            res &= test.Equals(standardTest);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Result of testing are : "+res.ToString());
    }
}
```

So whenever any object implementing `ITest` calls Equals() method on another `object`, instead of calling default `object.Equals()` it calls the one overridden in ITest instead.
Thanks.

Comment: An interface default method will only be used if the class doesn't implement that method itself. So you can't use that feature to override anything.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I'm still confuse though. Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236305/do-interfaces-derive-from-system-object-c-sharp-spec-says-yes-eric-says-no-re), I'm not sure why an interface cannot define it's own object.Equals() override method. So far I have to guess that's somehow because an interface is a subtype of object like any other type, so it can call object.Equals() for example, but cannot define it's own override because, somehow again, it has no members, even with new interface default implementation member feature ...

Comment: You just can't. The primary purpose of these default methods is for extending an interface between software versions. Without breaking code written by a 3rd party. But allowing you to provide a different implementation on some of the classes you control. Allowing an interface to define the only possible implementation, doesn't make much sense in this context.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yep i guess so. I end up intersperse an abstract class in between my Interface and my concrete class to override `Equals(object other)` (and `GetHashCode()`).